# Bootstrap mobile menu opening behind first section content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay I am having an issue with my bootstrap 3 mobile menu, it is opening under my first section content. After you scroll down it works fine, it just has that issue on the first section.

[You can see the issue here.](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/) Just reduce the screen size till you see the mobile menu button.

Also here is my html for my nav:

```
<div class="navbar">

<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

        <!-- Brand -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navbar-brand scroll-top"><img class="logo" width="45" height="45" alt="lightning bolt logo" src="img/logo.png"></img></a>

        <!-- Mobile Navigation -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="ion-navicon toggle-icon"></span>
        </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Main Navigation -->
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="myScrollSpy" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#section1" data-id="section1" class="scroll-link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2" data-id="section2" class="scroll-link">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3" data-id="section3" class="scroll-link">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section4" data-id="section4" class="scroll-link">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section5" data-id="section5" class="scroll-link">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section6" data-id="section6" class="scroll-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>

</div>
```

I have double checked my files and nothing is causing this, anyone ran into this issue before?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding `z-index: 9999;` style to `.navbar` class should work. The content from first section is overlapping with the navbar. Adding a high enough `z-index` makes sure that it'd be above every other element on the page.

```
.navbar {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Awesome that was it! I tried it earlier but had it applied to the wrong class! Thank you

Comment: Ok so this works but when you open a modal the navbar is above it because it scrolls with the page, you can see the [issue](http://aliensix.com/mytheme/) here, I tried a couple of different things but I cant get it the way I want, any suggestions?

Comment: I can't find any modal on that page. Have you tried assigning higher (than navbar) `z-index` to the modal?

Comment: @ve1jdramas how? Could you please give your solution?

Comment: great answer - so weird they didn't build this in ...?!?